# My emulator does not launch "process terminated"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emulation

I'm trying to open an emulator from android studio and it keeps giving me this error:

dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key Referenced from: /Users/[system_name]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1) Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet in /Users/[system_name]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of the Android studio version which you've installed. Please install version 2020.3.1 version.

Comment: There's only one version for installation on android studio website. I've downloaded the same version.

Comment: I thought maybe android studio software is downloading the wrong emulator which does not resolve with the version of my macOS. ( I use macOS 10.14 (Mojave) and cannot update at the moment cuz it keeps crashing. )

Comment: i have 2020.3.1 and i still have the same problem

Comment: @KamandShayegan Please check the following link for getting other Android studio versions, https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by downgrading the Emulator:

- 1. Download an old version of emulator (in my case i used **emulator-darwin_x64-7425822** [download from here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-742582.zip))
- 2. Replace the **emulator** folder you downloaded with the one in your sdk folder (sould normally be here `~/Library/Android/sdk`)

You can also fix it by upgrading your macOS version to the latest one.